# The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found.. - Asp.Net - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

When I launch the website locally it works fine, however when I upload this to the server I get "The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found.." for my App_Code folder

my ".aspx.cs" class

```
using XXXXXX.App_Code;
```

Any clues as to why?

Comment: Are you uploading all of the proper binaries?

Comment: The rest of the error message is "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" The `using` directive is obviously there. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: yes I'm aware, but it compiles correctly and works locally

Comment: try changing the .net version to 4.0.in project setting.

Comment: @dtb what assembly reference would I be missing?

Comment: @david it's set to 4.5

Answer (score 6):

You want to change whatever inside `App_Code` folder to `Compile`.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this option, I only have, File Name, Custom Tool and full path name

Comment: Please make sure you click on a Class. If still doesn't work, please post a screenshot of `Solution Explorer ` (expend all items).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `ASP.Net Web Forms Application` under `File > New > Project > Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.Net Web Forms Application`?

Comment: Not really, I imported an existing website, visual studio chose the "website" type for me

Comment: You are using `Web Site Projects`. Here is the differences - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Comment: I don't know why Visual Studio convert to Web Site Project automatically. If your application doesn't have a lot of pages, I prefer creating a new `Web Application Project/Web Forms Application` and copy old codes to new one manually.

Comment: haha thanks, I just saw your answer as I finished to converting it manually with good old ctrl + c, ctrl + v lol
nevermind it didn't take me long, now to test it out on the real server, wish me luxk!

Answer (score 1):

You may be uploading to the server which doesn't have the correct version of .NET or the correct framework. I've had this issue updating my MVC3 website to a server which doesn't have MVC3 installed.

Make sure the Application Pool in IIS is referencing the correct version and that the server has the relevant framework(s) installed.

Also, in Visual Studio, under Items to deploy, make sure All files in this project folder are selected and that Exclude files from the App_Data folder is not checked.

---

If you built your site as a project (ie, not a website)

Right click on the Solution -> Configuration Manager and check that it exists for  Release and is checked to Build

---

If you built your website as a new website (ie, not via new project)

Right click on the solution and select Property Pages. Make sure the file is added under References. Make sure under Build, Build website before running is selected

Comment: @MikeBryant OK, sorry for confusing you. Within your website, right click on Solution and selection and select Property Pages. Make sure, under references, your file is there. And check that the website is set to build before running (under build)

Answer (score 0):

Create a \bin folder under your website and copy dlls you reference there.